# mongodump with different folder name

Tags: mongodb, backup, mongodump

Is there a way to dump mongo database to a specific folder name?
Lets say I have a db named **myDb**

When I use:

```
mongodump --db myDb
```

It generates a dump folder with a `myDb` folder inside it

Is it possible to get something like `dump/mySpecifiedFolder` from `mongodump`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot change the name of the `myDB` folder, since that's named for the database which it contains, but you can change the location of the `myDb` folder. To do this, use the `--out` / `-o` parameter.

From [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/#cmdoption-mongodump-out):

> **--out , -o**
>
> Specifies the directory where mongodump will write BSON files for the dumped databases. By default, mongodump saves output files in a directory named dump in the current working directory.

So, this command ...

```
mongodump --db myDb -o /some/path/
```

... would cause mongodump to create `/some/path/myDb`.

Comment: Thank for answer, I know we can change dump folder name with --out, but I was wondering if we can change database folder name.

Comment: No, the database folder is **always** named for the database which it contains. The folder name effectively acts as a key and since the value is important MongoDB insists on retaining control of that value.

Comment: since you can restore to a different database name in mongorestore, why database name is important in dump? After all I think I should rename folder programmatically after dump. The case of this problem is when you need to write a backup/restore program for your database and your program should handle database name changes during times(for example a misspelling in database name)

Comment: Any statements of how you think `mongodump` should behave might be best addressed to the MongoDB people.

Answer (score 2):

In my discovery of doing a mongodump, please note that the default location can be the Desktop when outputting.

**Example** 
"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin\mongodump.exe" --host localhost --port 27017 --db local --out dump/dpusers
On your Desktop, the dump folder will be created with the subfolder "dpusers" and inside that folder is another folder named the same as your database name.